# HOW TO SET UP TRUFFLE CONFIGURATIONS FOR SEPOLIA ETH

Tags: truffle, testnets, truffle-migration, sepolia

** HOW TO SET UP TRUFFLE CONFIGURATIONS FOR SEPOLIA ETH **

I want to know how to set up my config on truffle to be able to deploy my contract on the eth testnet, I already have an infura api key

Answer (score 1):

Note that [Truffle is deprecated](https://consensys.io/blog/consensys-announces-the-sunset-of-truffle-and-ganache-and-new-hardhat).

If you still want to use it though, here's what `truffle-config.js` may look like interact with Sepolia:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const private_key = 'PRIVATE_KEY';

module.exports = {
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.20',
    },
  },
  
  // Network configuration
  networks: {
    // Development network is by default Ganache
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*',
    },

    // Sepolia test network
    sepolia: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
        private_key, 
        `NODE_ENDPOINT`
      ),
      network_id: 11155111, // Sepolia's network id
    },
  },
};
```

Replace `PRIVATE_KEY` with the private key of your account funded with Sepolia ETH thatn will do the deployment.

Replace `NODE_ENDPOINT` with a Sepolia node. Eg you can get one from Chainstack or any other provider.

Comment: Thank you very much